# How do I change the line endings used by PExpect output

Tags: python-3.x, pexpect

The returned output from pexpect.run() includes \r\n at the end of every line.  Printing to the terminal using print(returnVal.decode()) correctly prints one line for each line returned.  When I examine the output I see that the byte string contains \r\n.  When I log that to a file I get double returns to the log file.  I'm on a Mac using Python 3.7.  Is there a way to set the preferred new line when writing the output?  I am using pythons logging class and using the info() method to write the string.  Output looks like this:

```
total 80
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxx  admin  1048 Nov 12 00:41 Constants.py

-rw-r--r--   1 xxxx  admin  5830 Nov 12 13:33 file1.py

-rw-r--r--   1 xxxx  admin  2255 Nov 12 00:51 file2.py
```

When it should look like:

```
total 80
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxx  admin  1048 Nov 12 00:41 Constants.py
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxx  admin  5830 Nov 12 13:33 file1.py
-rw-r--r--   1 xxxx  admin  2255 Nov 12 00:51 file2.py
```

Here is a simplified version of my original Logger class:

```
class Logger():
    def __init__( self, path ):
        msgFormat   = '%(asctime)s.%(msecs)d\t%(message)s'
        dateFormat  = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
        logging.basicConfig( format=msgFormat, datefmt=dateFormat, filename=path, level=logging.INFO )

    def Log ( self, theStr ):
        logging.info( str( theStr ))
```

The string being returned from Pexpect looks something like:

```
Line1\r\nLine2
```

Comment: The quick solution is to replace `\r\n` with a single `\n` before logging. Logging module seems to use `\n` for newline already so that isn't the problem.

Comment: @Asad I don't see that the logging module has a way to specify the line ending.  What I have read so far is that python 3 would use the platforms default line ending.  Since I'm on unix (Mac) that would use \r\n.  I guess the other way is to have pexpect set the line endings but I don't see a way to do that either.  I would hate to put a hack in place and be the middle man.  The logger ultimately controls the line format so it would be nice to have the work done there.

Comment: Which version of Mac are you running? I believe the default line ending on Mac OS X is now \n. You can do a simple `returnVal.decode().replace("\r\n", "\n")` and see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: On 10.15 using Python 3.7.  I'll do that quick test.

Comment: @Asan  Yep that fixed it but now I'm affecting the file format of the file line by line.  I'd rather we simply set the behavior of the logger and forget about it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you log the output, it's advisable to format the newlines before sending to logger. However, if you must override the logging module's newline parameter for FileHandler, and as an experiment, you can do so by monkey patching its `_open` method as the functionality isn't available by default.

I used source code for Python version 3.8 to get `_open` function's definition.

```
import logging

def custom_open(self):
    """
    Monkey patched _open function of class logging.FileHandler (Python 3.8)

    """
    return open(self.baseFilename, self.mode, encoding=self.encoding, newline='')

logging.FileHandler._open = custom_open

if __name__ == "__main__":

    pexpect_return = "Output\nTest"
    my_log = logging.getLogger("test_logger")
    my_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    my_log.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("test.log"))
    my_log.info(pexpect_return)
```

**How it works**

Python's logging module has a class `FileHandler`, which uses a method `_open` to create a file handler object to write and append to log files on disk. Its default implementation as of version 3.8 does not have the `newline` parameter so it uses default newlines.

*Monkey patching* is when you replace or update a method/function in one of your imported classes, as the program is running. This line `logging.FileHandler._open = custom_open` tells python to replace the `_open` method of the `FileHandler` class, with my `custom_open` method. Then later when I use `my_log.addHandler(logging.FileHandler("test.log"))`, the new `custom_open` method is used to open the file with newline paramater.

You can further confirm that the new method is used to open the file by adding a suffix to the file name like this:

`return open(self.baseFilename+"__Monkey_Patched", self.mode, encoding=self.encoding, newline='')`

If you will now run that demo code, the filename will be "test.log__Monkey_Patched".

This code, however, will not replace any newline characters which you pass to the logger as part of the string to log. You need to process that beforehand.

Comment: I'm not opening the file.  I call    logging.basicConfig(format=msgFormat, datefmt=dateFormat, filename=path, level=logging.INFO).  It looks like I should attempt to add newline = '\n' to the call.  I then call logging.info() to log the message.

Comment: Na... that, of course, didn't work.  I see you are just replacing the entire mechanism to get the functionality.  IOW:  You open the file instead of letting the logger class open it.  I would have to work out some details but your approach may work.  I copied the example but will look for a more direct way to ask the logger class to do the same.

Comment: Your example doesn't work.  I suppose it was originally from a class but items such as self and self.baseFilename does not exist.  If you will fix it I'd prefer the class version.

Comment: I had tested that demo code (Python 3.4) before posting here. I have now added an explanation so you can understand how it is supposed to work, and why it might not work for you.